# Inserting a string into a list of integers

Tags: python, list, type-conversion

I am trying to make a script where a '-' is put in between all odd digits in a given number (ie 991453 would be 9-9-145-3), but for some reason python wont allow me to insert a str into a list of integers. The error I keep on getting is 'TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting'

My code:

```
def DashInsert(text):

    list_int = map(int, list(text))

    for i in xrange(len(list_int)-1):
        if (list_int[i] % 2 == 1) and (list_int[i+1] % 2 == 1):
           print i
           list_int.insert(i+1,'-')

    return list_int
```

Here is my actual input and error:

> 999472

0

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "DashInsert.py", line 17, in

```
print DashInsert(string)
```

File "DashInsert.py", line 11, in DashInsert

```
if (list_int[i] % 2 == 1) and (list_int[i+1] % 2 == 1):
```

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Please show the actual input and the actual error trace back.

Comment: FYI this is happening because you are modifying (specifically, adding to) the list **while you are iterating over it**. This is almost never a good idea. I mean, look what you are doing. You turn everything to ints first, but then you find the one you want and you insert **a string** in the next position. Hence, next round your `%` is string formatting!

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I understand what you are saying but the if statement should not allow the inserted '-' to through right? So I dont understand why its not working

Comment: What? The insert takes place _inside_ the if statement. The '-' can _only_ be inserted if that expression evaluates to true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is because you are modifying the list that you are iterating over. When you insert `-` into the list, that becomes the target of `%` and you get a TypeError.

In Python, `%` is an operator for string formatting and `'-'` is a string; that is why you get a less than clear error:

```
>>> '-' % 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

For strings you use `%` this way:

```
>>> 'x %s y %s %i' % ('and', 'is', 13)
'x and y is 13'
```

The fix to your code is to append to a separate list:

```
def DashInsert(s):

    list_int = map(int, s)

    rtr=[]

    for i, e in enumerate(list_int[0:-1]):
        rtr.append(str(e))
        if e % 2 == 1 and list_int[i+1] % 2 == 1:
           rtr.append('-')
    rtr.append(str(list_int[-1]))    

    return rtr
```

Comment: This was great, it was exactly what I needed and I understand why you used i as an index for the list and e as the variable of the list. One quick question though, in your for loop why does python use i as an index and e as a variable? It would seem that both i and e would be variables of the enumerated list, sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Not a stupid question at all! The return from [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) is a tuple containing the index into the sequence and the item in that sequence with that index number (if the sequence supports indexing, which not all do). When I have `for i, e in enumerate(seq)` it unpacks into i and e that two member tuple. Clear?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this through regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 991453
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=[13579])(?=[13579])', r'-', str(s))
'9-9-145-3'
```

Comment: could you explain the r'(?<=[13579])(?=[13579])' part of your code? Also I am not allowed to import modules to solve this problem.

Comment: Since this is homework and obviously for a low-level CS class, don't worry about that part of his code. It's called a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) and you'll get to them later in your higher-level CS classes that cross over into the math behind it. Basically they let you describe a string by patterns even if you don't know what exactly it will say. If you are going to have to do this with no imports, your code will work, but don't modify the list in place while iterating. Instead, write down where hyphens should go and stick them in later.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is horrible code but it works-

```
number = 991453

number_list = []
for i, item in enumerate(str(number)):
    try:
        if int(item) % 2 != 0 and int(str(number)[i + 1]) % 2 != 0:
            number_list.append(item + '-')
        else:
            number_list.append(item)
    except:
        number_list.append(item)
print(''.join(number_list))
```

Edit: Actually, there's no need to make a list so we can do this-

```
number = 991453

dash_number = ''
for i, item in enumerate(str(number)):
    try:
        if int(item) % 2 != 0 and int(str(number)[i + 1]) % 2 != 0:
            dash_number += item + '-'
        else:
            dash_number += item
    except:
        dash_number += item
print(dash_number)
```

Edit: Here's how to do it without the try/except.

```
number = 991453

dash_number = ''
for i, item in enumerate(str(number)[:-1]):
    if int(item) % 2 != 0 and int(str(number)[i + 1]) % 2 != 0:
        dash_number += item + '-'
    else:
        dash_number += item
dash_number += str(number)[-1]

print(dash_number)
```